# get selected dropdown value without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdown outside the html table generated by PHP code. I have submit button in this table
 as explained by following code.

```
 <!doctype html>
            Select Year:
                   <select name=\"year\" id=\"year\"  style="width: 200px">
                      <option value=\"2014\">2014</option>
                      <option value=\"2015\">2015</option>
                    </select>

                Select Trimester: 
                    <select name=\"trimester\" id=\"trimester\" style="width: 200px">
                        <option value=\"1st\">1st</option>
                        <option value=\"2nd\">2nd</option>
                        <option value=\"3rd\">3rd</option>
                    </select> 

<?php
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                      $ict_id= $row['id'];
                      $name= $row['name'];
          echo "<tr><form name=\"form$id\" id=\"form$id\"><td>".$name."</td>

        <td>
          <select name=\"absent$id\" id=\"absent$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name=\"creative$id\" id=\"creative$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name=\"problem$id\" id=\"problem$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
            <option value=\"1\">1</option>
            <option value=\"2\">2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

    <td>
    <input type=\"button\" name=\"submit$id\"  id=\"submit$id\" value=\"Submit\"      onclick=\"getVal(this.id)\">
?>
```

On clicking this  button it loads following  javascript function.

```
function getVal(clicked_id){

}
```

My problem is how can I get the selected value of year and trimester and use inside the getVal function .

Any helps are welcomed.

Comment: console.log($('#' + clicked_id).val());

Comment: `onclick=\"getVal($id)\"`  try it

Answer (score 0):

Add `onchange` event to the select element and pass id to this like this:

```
<select onchange="getVal(this.id)" name=\"absent$id\" id=\"absent$id\" style=\"width: 200px\">
```

Call `getVal` function like this:

```
function getVal(clicked_id){
    alert(clicked_id);
}
```